# Getting NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Tags: android, getjson, numberformatexception

Getting this error while attaching data to my arrayList.

this is my JsonResponse

```
[
    {
        "ChatId": 13,
        "Name": [],
        "LoginUserId": "123xc-xcv4r4",
        "Message": [
            {
                "message": "Message 1 ",
                "Status": 0,
                "Date": "2017-09-11T12:56:21.07",
                "Name": "name",
                "UserId": "12",
                "Id": 0,
                "Latitude": "",
                "Longitude": ""
            },
        ],
        "UserId": ["3434scjdcndne4r4ir" ]
    }
]
```

I am Attaching above response as

```
     Type type = new TypeToken<List<jsonModel>>() {
                    }.getType();
   arraylist= Conversions.getGson().fromJson(response, type);
```

I am notusing any double value in my code

and error is getting at

```
 arraylist= Conversions.getGson().fromJson(response, type);

om.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:323)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:313)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory
```

this is my pojo class

```
private int ChatId;
    private ArrayList<String> Name = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String LoginUserId;
    private ArrayList<AllUserMessages> Message = new 
    ArrayList<AllUserMessages>();
    private ArrayList<String> UserId = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Please help me to get out of this issue

Comment: `Latitude": "", Longitude": " ` is your problem they should be like Latitude":0.00, Longitude:0.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Try to change your `AllUserMessages` class `Latitude, Longitude` variables type `double` to `String`

2) Or change `Latitude, Longitude` from server site to double.

Comment: Thanks Dude. It worked

Comment: Upvoted.........